How to automate the retry mechanism when a glue crawler is failed?
I have a glue crawler which is scheduled to be triggered on a daily basis at a particular timeslot. Whenever the glue crawler gets failed, I have to manually re-trigger it.
to avoid manual intervention, is there a way to automate the retry mechanism when a glue crawler is failed?
I haven't found any such retry options in the glue crawler where I can set the number of retries.
